# install ruby on rails but got error when starting the server with "rails s"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have installed ruby on rails on my ubuntu. Did rails new 
then cd into  and started rails server with "rails s". here is the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
61: from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
60: from bin/rails:3:in `load'
59: from /home/leo/Desktop/xxy/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
58: from /home/leo/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:70:in `require'
57: from /home/leo/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:70:in `require'
56: from /home/leo/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
55: from /home/leo/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `load'
54: from /home/leo/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
53: from /home/leo/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
52: from /home/leo/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
51: from /home/leo/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
50: from /home/leo/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
49: from /home/leo/Desktop/xxy/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
48: from /home/leo/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
47: from /home/leo/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
46: from /home/leo/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
45: from /home/leo/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
44: from /home/leo/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
43: from /home/leo/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:83:in `register'
42: from /home/leo/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
41: from /home/leo/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
40: from /home/leo/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
39: from /home/leo/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
38: from /home/leo/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/command/base.rb:65:in `perform'
37: from /home/leo/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
36: from /home/leo/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
35: from /home/leo/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
34: from /home/leo/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `perform'
33: from /home/leo/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `tap'
32: from /home/leo/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:145:in `block in perform'
31: from /home/leo/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
30: from /home/leo/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
29: from /home/leo/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
28: from /home/leo/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
27: from /home/leo/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
26: from /home/leo/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:83:in `register'
25: from /home/leo/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
24: from /home/leo/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
23: from /home/leo/Desktop/xxy/config/application.rb:7:in `<main>'
22: from /home/leo/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.0.1/lib/bundler.rb:114:in `require'
21: from /home/leo/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.0.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `require'
20: from /home/leo/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.0.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `each'
19: from /home/leo/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.0.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block in require'
18: from /home/leo/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.0.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `each'
17: from /home/leo/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.0.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `block (2 levels) in require'
16: from /home/leo/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
15: from /home/leo/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
14: from /home/leo/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:83:in `register'
13: from /home/leo/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
12: from /home/leo/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
11: from /home/leo/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/uglifier-4.1.20/lib/uglifier.rb:5:in `<main>'
10: from /home/leo/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
 9: from /home/leo/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
 8: from /home/leo/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
 7: from /home/leo/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
 6: from /home/leo/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
 5: from /home/leo/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:83:in `register'
 4: from /home/leo/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
 3: from /home/leo/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
 2: from /home/leo/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs.rb:4:in `<main>'
 1: from /home/leo/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs.rb:5:in `<module:ExecJS>'
/home/leo/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:58:in `autodetect': Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/rails/execjs for a list of available runtimes. (ExecJS::RuntimeUnavailable)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You lack JS runtime environment. Try adding

```
gem 'mini_racer'
```

to your `Gemfile`, then `bundle install` and then `rails s` again.